# Feature multi language joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, multilingual

I would like to know if there any extensions that meet my requirement below for joomla multilanguage:

- Detect language automatically based on location (GeoIP)
- Automatically translate content without input two or more translation content
- can have prefix url like domain.com/en/ or domain.com/es/, etc.

Please let me know if there any suits extension above features.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JoomFish automatically detect language for your location, and Joomfish makes prefixes like you need (domain.com/en or domain.com/fr), but I believe there is no any extensions to translate your content automatically...